# Two different types of ValueError to handle in try except block?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working on a function to handle timestamps in a pandas `dataframe`. These timestamps have timezone offsets which must always be between the range -12 and +14.

Example of a sound timestamp string offset:

```
x = '2019-11-11T07:08:09.640-4:00'
```

Example of a nonsense timestamp string offset:

```
y = '2019-11-11T07:08:09.640-31:00'
```

Then when I try to format them (works fine):

```
dateutil.parser.parse(x).isoformat()
'2019-11-11T07:08:09.640000-04:00'
```

But then with nonsense timezone offset (Does not work):

```
dateutil.parser.parse(y).isoformat()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: offset must be a timedelta strictly between -timedelta(hours=24) and timedelta(hours=24).
```

So, I tried to make a function that uses try and except for this `ValueError`:

```
def rogue_tz_offsets(t):
    try:
        return dateutil.parser.parse(t).isoformat()
    except ValueError:
        return dateutil.parser.parse(t).replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat()
```

e.g.

```
rogue_tz_offsets('2019-11-11T07:08:09.640-31:00')
'2019-11-11T07:08:09.640000'
```

Good, that works, the nonsensical timezone offset -31 was removed. Now with a sound timezone offset:

```
rogue_tz_offsets('2019-11-11T07:08:09.640-4:00')
'2019-11-11T07:08:09.640000-04:00'
```

Good, this time the sound timezone offset -4:00 is kept.

So far so good, except that there is one more case in my data, where the timestamp string to pass to `rogue_tz_offsets()` is just the string 'other'.

```
rogue_tz_offsets('other')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 7, in rogue_tz_offsets
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 1358, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 649, in parse
    raise ValueError("Unknown string format:", timestr)
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'other')
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 9, in rogue_tz_offsets
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 1358, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 649, in parse
    raise ValueError("Unknown string format:", timestr)
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'other')
```

The problem for me is it's a `ValueError`, which I'm already accounting for. In this case, if I was able to distinguish the two types of `ValueError` I would like to return:

```
return dateutil.parser.parse('2100-01-01 00:00:00').isoformat()
```

So just setting it to a far away future date.

My function in full:

```
def rogue_tz_offsets(t):
    try:
        return dateutil.parser.parse(t).isoformat()
    except ValueError:
        # handle case where the t is the string 'other'
        return dateutil.parser.parse('2100-01-01 00:00:00').isoformat()
    except ValueError:
        # handle the case where the timezone offset is out of range by removing it
        return t.replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat()
```

How can I distinguish the two types of `ValueError` to apply different handling to each case?

Comment: Mmm You may have to actually inspect the error message. For sure, that is a clunky approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check exception message to find out exact reason:

```
def rogue_tz_offsets(t):
   try:
       d = dateutil.parser.parse(t)
       if -12 * 60 * 60 <= d.utcoffset().total_seconds() <= 14 * 60 * 60:
          return d.isoformat()
       return d.replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat()

   except ValueError as e:
       if str(e) == 'Unknown string format':
           return dateutil.parser.parse('2100-01-01 00:00:00').isoformat()

       if str(e) == 'offset must be a timedelta strictly between -timedelta(hours=24) and timedelta(hours=24).':
           return dateutil.parser.parse(t).replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but found a case where the returned results were still out of bounds timezone offsets: `x = '2019-11-19T22:51:34.619000+17:00'` then `rogue_tz_offsets(x)` returns `'2019-11-19T22:51:34.619000+17:00'` where I was aiming to drop the tzoffset with None. Any ideas?